# Set Messaging platform on Dialogflow v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

Is it possible to set messaging platform for DialogFlow when using DetectIntent from API?

I'm using node.js API
https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2

I receive message from telegram with my code, send it to DialogFlow.
And I want DialogFlow to use Telegram tab as a response for my intent.
Found only platform parameter for webhook but have not idea how to use it.

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Dialogflow with Telegram you can use [Dialogflow's builtin Telegram one-click integration](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/telegram).

You can't use Dialogflow's query API to set the integration to Telegram, but can use the [payload attribute](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#QueryParameters.FIELDS.payload) of a [queryParams object](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#queryparameters) in your [detectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) request to identify the request later in [Dialogflow's webhook request](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookRequest) to your fulfillment endpoint.